# Why is Minitest running so slow for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

Minitest is taking 52 seconds to run 3 tests, can you help me diagnose and correct the delay:

```
time bin/rake test
Running via Spring preloader in process 6302
Run options: --seed 53674

# Running:

...

Finished in 0.981134s, 3.0577 runs/s, 3.0577 assertions/s.

3 runs, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips


real    0m52.954s
user    0m0.431s
sys 0m0.148s
```

Nothing wrong with the tests, i guess it's a test config issue? Test code here:

actual tests here:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial"
  end

end
```

I ran `spring stop`, but this has not sped things up in any way.

I note that my app does not have a `spring` directory.

Comment: Only 3 assertions... Show us your tests.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like an `ActionController::TestCase` not an `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`.

This should be `test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb`. Could be the use of `IntegrationTest`, since typically this is reserved for more complex interactions and includes many more features.

> An integration test spans multiple controllers and actions, tying them all together to ensure they work together as expected. It tests more completely than either unit or functional tests do, exercising the entire stack, from the dispatcher to the database.

Try this code instead:

```
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  # ...
end
```

## EDIT

I ran a single very simple test comparison and came up pretty short. Does not seem to me like it would cause such a dramatic difference.

```
# Running tests:

.

Finished test in 0.605962s, 1.6503 tests/s, 4.9508 assertions/s.

1 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Versus

```
# Runnnig tests:

.

Finished tests in 0.297522s, 3.3611 tests/s, 10.0833 assertions/s.
1 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Still close to 3 times longer when using `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`.

It's strange in your case as well because these are static pages.

Are there any changes to `test_helper.rb`? If so, can you show us?

Comment: Do try and post plain text as plain text, not as an image that nobody can read.

Comment: Changing to `ActionController::TestCase` results in an  `ActionController::UrlGenerationError:` error. 

I wonder whether this is a machine performance issue, any pointers as to how to narrow this performance issue down?

Comment: The errors your seeing has to do with your URL paths. Instead of doing `get static_pages_about_url`, try something like `get :about`. Get this working to help narrow down performance issue. Otherwise there are tons of other things: https://blog.codeship.com/faster-rails-tests/